# Что должен возвращать Middleware::handle в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5

В документации есть примеры того, как метод handle в Middleware-классах возвращает `$next($request);` и `redirect('/')`. Что ещё я могу возвращать в нем?
Документация в Laravel (в противоположность php.net) вообще оформлена странным образом - в виде небольших статей для ознакомления; списка методов, объектов и другой конкретной информации в ней нет...

И еще небольшой вопрос: в каком порядке вызываются методы handle, если Middleware-классов несколько? Для теста в `kernel.php` зарегистрировал 3 класса, чтобы в каждом метод `handle` просто выводил число - порядок класса при регистрации в `kernel.php`, и я получил следующее: `2; 1; 2; 3;`. Что за странный порядок и почему метод из второго класса вызывался дважды?

Comment: А что еще вы хотели бы возвращать в handle? Посредник на то и посредник, чтобы пропускать через себя запрос и перенаправлять куда следует.

Comment: @ArturHan, я лишь хочу знать его полную функциональность, доступные возможности.

Comment: Можно с помощью посредника делать запись логов в файл или что-нибудь в базу данных прописать